# What event has been triggered when a Microsoft Bot is installed to a Microsoft Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to Microsoft Bot and Microsoft teams. I'm working on Bot Framework 4.9 and I need to show some text message to the Microsoft teams channel while the Bot is getting installed programmatically to the teams channel for the very first time.

I did not find clear information in Microsoft documents, what event is triggered when a Microsoft Bot is installed to a Microsoft Teams?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Please let me know if you have any specific update.

Comment: Please take a look at [Bot Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition) sent when a member is added or Bot added in Teams

Answer (score 1):

> The `conversationUpdate` event with the `membersAdded` object in the payload is sent when either a bot is added to a team or a new user is added to a team where a bot has been added. Microsoft Teams also adds eventType.teamMemberAdded in the channelData object <sup>[[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#:%7E:text=The%20conversationUpdate%20event%20with%20the,teamMemberAdded%20in%20the%20channelData%20object.)]</sup>

Using this event you can access users data(name, email) if needed.

However when your bot gets initialized/called to a user(personal context) conversationupdate gets called again, you're probably passing user state as an argument like this : `BOT = WelcomeUserBot(USER_STATE)` This user state itself is storing all the memory/conversation data of the bot `MEMORY = MemoryStorage(); USER_STATE = UserState(MEMORY)`

Tldr; `conversationupdate` event within `membersAdded` object is the answer

Comment: I'm looking for the event when a bot is linked to a teams for the very first time only.

Comment: conversationUpdate is still the correct (and only) event for this, but what you do is check, as part of the "update", -who- got added. If the Id of the user who got added matches the id of your bot, then you know your bot has just been added to the Team, and you simply ignore any future conversationUpdate events. The article Javin linked to shows this, in the section called "Example code: Checking whether bot was the added member"

Comment: @MarsRoverII conversationUpdate is the only event which gets called the very first time when some1 goes to the teams app store, selects your bot & clicks install, even the official docs says its so. I'm not getting why you think its not? Can you elaborate please.